# Java Newton Iteration

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make a square root calculator with my own function which is sqrt and borrowing a already made one to test accuracy. The issue is every time I output my guess to the screen after putting it into the function the numbers just return as the same number inputted but it has a .0 on it. An example is, when I put in the number 2 I get back 2.0 which is wrong. Please help :)

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
/**
 * Main method.
 *
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);

    double root;
    /*
     * Put your main program code here; it may call myMethod as shown
     */
    System.out.println("Please enter a root to be calculated:");
    root = data.nextDouble();
    double actual = root;
    sqrt(root);
    sqrt_(actual);
    System.out.println(root);
    System.out.println(actual);
    /*
     * Close input and output streams
     */

}

/**
 * Computes estimate of square root of x to within relative error 0.01%.
 *
 * @param x
 *            positive number to compute square root of
 * @return estimate of square root
 */
private static double sqrt(double x) {

    double epilson = 0.0001;
    double approx = 1;
    int count = 0;
    while ((Math.abs(approx - (x / approx)) > (0.0001 * approx))
            && (count < 100)) {
        approx = 0.5 * (approx + (x / approx));
        count++;
    }
    return approx;

}

public static double sqrt_(double c) {
    if (c < 0) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
    double EPS = 1E-15;
    double t = c;
    while (Math.abs(t - c / t) > EPS * t) {
        t = (c / t + t) / 2.0;
    }
    return t;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are simply forgetting to assign your return values.

```
root = sqrt(root);
actual = sqrt_(actual);
```

Comment: that fixed it! thank you very much! I'm curious though is my sqrt function (says sqrt not sqrt_) efficient? I feel like there should be more to it